# User shows different rep count between two posts on questions page

Tags: bug, reputation, question-lists

I was perusing the questions on Arqade, and while scrolling down the question list on the questions page, I noticed a discrepancy in rep count for a user between two different posts.

[image: User has 27 rep on one post, and 17 on another.]

This was on page load, and not after loading new questions from on the page. Not really sure why this happened, but I don't think I've ever seen it happen before.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/